# MySQL: need help making a query faster

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.7

I wrote a query that finds me records in `discovery` table that contain a needle from `whitelisted` (LIKE %needle%) and don't have a record in `logs` table (and some other easy to understand filtering):

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT discovery.id, discovery.resource AS url, discovery.event_datetime, whitelisted.keyword 
    FROM discovery
    INNER JOIN whitelisted
    ON discovery.`resource` LIKE concat('%', whitelisted.`keyword`, '%')
    LEFT JOIN `logs`
    ON `logs`.discovery_id = discovery.id
    WHERE
    discovery.event_datetime >= NOW()
    AND
    discovery.provider = 'XXX'
    AND
    `logs`.id IS NULL
    AND
    discovery.resource NOT LIKE '%SOMETHING-TO-EXCLUDE%'
    LIMIT 0, 20
) logless_resources
GROUP BY logless_resources.url
ORDER BY logless_resources.event_datetime ASC
```

*discovery table:* 143k rows

- id UNSIGNED INT AI PRIMARY
- resource VARCHAR(1024) INDEX
- provider ENUM
- event_datetime DATETIME
- created_at DATETIME

*whitelisted table:* 535 rows (*not* thousands, just 0.5k)

- id UNSIGNED INT AI PRIMARY
- keyword VARCHAR(128) INDEX
- provider ENUM
- created_at DATETIME

*logs:* 585k rows

- id UNSIGNED INT AI PRIMARY
- discovery_id UNSIGNED INT FK to discovery.id

Right now this takes 90 seconds - can it be made faster?

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY field` produces random, non-deterministic, result, when `field` is not unique, so it makes no sense. Otherwise, if `field` is unique, the `GROUP BY` is excess, so it makes no sense again.

Comment: ``ON discovery.`resource` LIKE concat('%', whitelisted.`keyword`, '%')`` produces a fullscan. So `LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL` is less effective than `WHERE NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: +1 for a very good first question. `<nitpick>` it might be better to show your DDL as the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE blah\G`?`<nitpick>`

Comment: @Akina I need the `url` in the resultset to be unique, hence the GROUP BY. I understand your rationale, but I did see a difference with and without GROUP BY.  I also tried replacing `LEFT JOIN .. WHERE .. IS NULL` with `WHERE NOT EXISTS` as per your suggestion and found it to be more than twice as slow, unless I did it wrong (https://gist.github.com/NinoSkopac/746ff4fc38696e747923c6c7f3d6a640). I do appreciate your help tho.

Comment: @Vérace I've never heard about `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, but I've tried it now and it's pretty cool - thanks man.

Comment: So, now you have "the knowledge", you can edit your question! :-) p.s. you're welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The focus needs to be on the "derived" table, since it delivers only 20 rows to the outer parts.

```
        SELECT  d.id, d.resource AS url, d.event_datetime,
                wl.keyword
            FROM  discovery AS d
            INNER JOIN  whitelisted AS wl
                    ON d.`resource` LIKE concat('%', wl.`keyword`, '%')
            LEFT JOIN  `logs`  ON `logs`.discovery_id = d.id
            WHERE  d.event_datetime >= NOW()
              AND  d.provider = 'XXX'
              AND  `logs`.id IS NULL
              AND  d.resource NOT LIKE '%SOMETHING-TO-EXCLUDE%'
            LIMIT  0, 20
```

Starting with the `WHERE` clause...

```
              d.event_datetime >= NOW() -- last in index (range)
              d.provider = 'XXX'  -- first in the index because of "="
              `logs`.id IS NULL   -- another table, not very selective
              d.resource NOT LIKE '%SOMETHING-TO-EXCLUDE%'  -- probably useless
```

So `discovery` needs `INDEX(provider, event_datetime)`, in that order.

Now to get to the other tables

```
ON `logs`.discovery_id = d.id
```

Logs needs `INDEX(discovery_id)`

```
ON d.`resource` LIKE concat('%', wl.`keyword`, '%')
```

This is terrible for optimizing.  It will need to test every row of either `whitelisted` or `discovery`.  Since I have guessed that `discovery` will be the first table, I expect a tedious scan of `whitelisted`.

Do you care that there is no `ORDER BY`?  That is, you could be getting a random 20 rows, not the newest 20, not the oldest, etc.

(Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` when presenting a schema; it is much more precise than prose.)

Comment: Hey Rick, thanks for your input. I went through your response and my main takeaway was that using ON MATCH() would be quicker, but I don't wanna fetch all keywords first (`word 1 word2 ...`) because IMO that'd entail using another query. I already have those indexes. I most certainly do care about the `ORDER BY`, that's why the "derived" table is in a subquery, so I can only get the first 20 rows. I've ended up ditching the LIMIT clause and just doing the query less frequently, and queing the processing of the results internally in PHP. thanks for the `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac - Oops, I missed the `NOT`.  So, I removed my `FULLTEXT` recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a query that has multiple criteria on the same table a compound index is needed. MySQL will only use a single index for a table (or alias) so make sure its the right one.

First look at `discovery` since its on the left of the join. Start with items referenced and then ranges. So:

- provider
- event_datetime

Elements like `resource` because of the `LIKE %x%` expression can't use and index. For a small table we relay that (`provider`,`event_datetime`) restruct the table small enough to be be significant about including `resource` in the index.

So:

```
CREATE INDEX provider_event_datetime ON discovery (provider,event_datetime);
```

Note: is whitelisted.provider need to be the same as the discovery_provider?

A limit on the inner query is quite unpredictable without an `ORDER BY`.

The remaining join on `logs` is looking it up by the PK. No additional indexing is required there.

Look at `EXPLAIN {query}` to examine what indexes it is using and how.

Comment: Hey Dan, I ran the query and which added two indexes, which reduced the query time from 90 to 80 seconds on average. "is whitelisted.provider need to be the same as the discovery_provider?" - I don't quite understand that. What is PK? Here's my EXPLAIN query: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TI0C6h10h-dMi7u_YKqPltLrpvbsHTq6atkoO3TaVLU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: "is whitelisted.provider need to be the same as the discovery_provider?"  I was wondering if you missed a 'JOIN ON whitelisted.provider = discovery.provider` in your question. PK -> primary key. Since it results in a BKA on the LIKE whitelist are large consider increasing [join_buffer_size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size) to see if it has an effect.

Comment: Tried increasing join_buffer_size to 1.5GB, it didn't affect the query time. Thanks for your effort, I gave you a +1 :)